# Make a point move on the plot without clearing earlier plots in matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

I am trying to make a point move on the random plots in matplotlib. Please refer to the following code.

```
import numpy as np 
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 
from time import sleep
plt.ion()
a = np.array([[1,1],[5,5],[2,4],[7,8],[4,2],[10,11]])
b = []
for i in range(a.shape[0]/2):
    b.append([a[2*i],a[2*i+1]])
b = np.array(b)

for i in b:    # retain this plot
    plt.plot(i[:,0],i[:,1])

for i in b:
    t = np.linspace(0,1,100)
    for k in t:
        x = (1-k)*i[0,0]+k*i[1,0]
        y = (1-k)*i[0,1]+k*i[1,1]
        sleep(0.1)
        # plt.gcf().clear()
        plt.scatter([x],[y])
        plt.draw()
```

When I run this code, a point is moving on the plots but it is leaving traces. But, I want a single point move without leaving traces and retain the plot I made before plotting the point. If I use clear() (I commented it in the code), it is clearing the whole plot and plotting only the point.

I tried to use **FuncAnimation()**, but I am finding difficulty in plotting all the other plots whose number is more than 300.

Is there any method I can use. Plase, help.

Thanks

Comment: You're plotting a new dot with plt.scatter([x],[y]) at each loop step, not modifying the dot properties.

Comment: @Wli I did not understand "modifying the dot properties" part. Could you please elaborate a bit.

Comment: check the duplicate.

Comment: I checked the other question. In a way, it is not duplicate as it does not have a background plot on which a point moves. I want to have a background plot with hundreds of lines (only three lines are shown in the sample code).

Comment: You can inspire yourself from the answer. The OP posted a similar code than yours.